# Word order: «Я тот же, но без тебя прежним не буду». And would it be correct to use «тобой» and «таким» instead?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова, порядок-слов

Does the sentence «Я тот же, но без тебя прежним не буду» ("I'm the same, but I won't be the same without you") sound natural with the words in that particular order?

Also, in this case it wouldn't be correct to use «тобой» and «таким», right? I'm trying to ask whether the following sentence is also correct or not and means the same thing: «Я тот же, но без тобой таким не буду».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the sentence «Я тот же, но без тебя прежним не буду» ("I'm the same, but I won't be the same without you") sound natural with the words in that particular order?

It does.

More literally, it means "I won't be the person I used to be", but that's just the difference between the idiomatic ways of putting it in the two languages. Yours is perfectly idiomatic.

> Also, in this case it wouldn't be correct to use «тобой» and «таким», right? I'm trying to ask whether the following sentence is also correct or not and means the same thing: «Я тот же, но без тобой таким не буду».

No, it wouldn't. It's *с тобой* but *без тебя*. *С* (when meaning "with") governs the instrumental, *без* governs the genitive.

Also, *такой* means "such", it doesn't really work in this phrase. "The same" would be *тот же* ("the same person") or *такой же* ("the same kind of person"). Neither works better than *прежний* in this phrase.